# JqueryUI Dialog

Tags: jquery, dialog

I have a problem when I try to use JqueryUI Dialog it doesn't show anything but doesn't give an error either.

The code is:

```
var div = "<div id='dialog'><p>Sometext</p></div>";
$(function() {
    $('#dialog').dialog();
});
```

I implemented

```
// @require     jquery-1.9.1.min.js
// @require     http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css
// @require     http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js
```

On the top of the script so I don't know what the problem is.

Hope someone can help me.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you checked console??

Comment: Yes it doesn't give any error in console

Comment: is your #dialog div already in the DOM? Also you'll not want to call `.dialog();` on every div. You should specify the ID

Comment: go to page source and see whether the files you included are found or not, or try to find errors with fire bug console.

Comment: Just checking: that syntax looks like it's for Chrome(?) extension, but it's not mentioned anywhere in the question. Is that right?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the DIV to the DOM:

```
var div = "<div id='dialog'><p>Sometext</p></div>";
$(function() {
    $("body").append(div);
    $('#dialog').dialog();
});
```

Comment: That's not strictly necessary; you can also do `$(div).dialog();`. (The problem with the original code is just that `#dialog` doesn't select anything that's not in the DOM.)

Comment: I didn't realize widgets could use disconnected elements like that. although it makes sense.